# What's the difference between horrify and terrify?

Tags: american-english, british-english

What's the difference between horrify and terrify  plz explain it in an easy way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm speaking for American-English: Horrify implies a shocking incident, potential gore. Terrify implies a recurring or long-term incident,  a more psychological effect

This is a very broad question, but thse are my thoughts. I'm sure colloquial differences exist and you'll get varied answers.

This is my first input on this site, please go easy!

Comment: Thx .☀Have a
nice weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Horrify is a variety of bad feelings relating to a experience.

> Horror from dictionary.com : an overwhelming and painful feeling caused by something frightfully shocking, terrifying, or revolting; a shuddering fear

Terror is simply extreme fear.

> Terror from dictionary.com : extreme fear.

Usually if you feel terror, you will also feel horror. However, you often don't feel terror if you feel horror.

You might feel horror from the shock of seeing a ghost, and terror from the fear of seeing a ghost.

However, if you discovered that for the whole day you had some marmalade on your chin without realising, you'd feel horror but not terror.

The two overlap quite a lot though.